# No puedo anidar joins con sentencias SQL en Access 2013

Tags: sql, join, ms-access

Pruebo esto en *Access 2013* y dice que hay un error, pero no especifica cuál.

```
SELECT DISTINCT factura.n_factura, factura.data, factura.import, factura.concepte, departament.nom, programa.nom, despesa.nom, emisor.nom, destinatari.nom
FROM factura
INNER JOIN departament  ON factura.departament = departament.codi
INNER JOIN programa ON factura.programa = programa.codi
INNER JOIN despesa ON factura.despesa = despesa.codi
INNER JOIN emisor ON factura.emisor = emisor.codi
INNER JOIN destinatari ON factura.destinatari = destinatari.codi;
```

He probado los ejemplos de *MSDN* y es muy molesto ver lo mal hecha que está la documentación oficial de *Microsoft*.

¿Cómo puedo anidar los `JOIN` sin que aparezcan errores?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te muestra? ¿Cual es la versión de access que estas usando? ¿Haz consultado el artículo que corresponde a la versión que estás usando? ¿Todas la tablas tienen los campos requeridos y la misma cantidad e campos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final lo solucioné volviendo a generar la consulta desde el propio access y modificando, y quedó como posteé a priori (también generado por access y modificado por mi), pero esta vez funcionando.

Bastante raro el hecho de ver a un software de Microsoft dando respuestas distintas al mismo estímulo, eh? (guiño-guiño, meme de genius con logo de "máicroso" en la gorra)
En fin, gracias por las respuestas de todos modos y si alguien tiene el mismo problema, borrar y volver a generar consulta!

Un saludo

Comment: gracias por responder :D saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Considerando la respuesta de mi buen amigo [@sstan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18951/sstan) y la respuesta vista en [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3031589/3613462) Se debe tener lo siguiente:

```
SELECT DISTINCT factura.n_factura, factura.data, factura.import, factura.concepte, departament.nom, programa.nom, despesa.nom, emisor.nom, destinatari.nom
FROM (((((factura
INNER JOIN departament  ON factura.departament = departament.codi)
INNER JOIN programa ON factura.programa = programa.codi)
INNER JOIN despesa ON factura.despesa = despesa.codi)
INNER JOIN emisor ON factura.emisor = emisor.codi)
INNER JOIN destinatari ON factura.destinatari = destinatari.codi)
```

Comment: Hola fredyfx. Veo que resucitastes una pregunta perdida :)  Vi tu comentario, y tras hacer una verificación, el último nivel de paréntesis no debería ser necesario, aunque no creo que haga daño tampoco. Aunque debo agregar que la prueba la hice con MS Access 2010, no 2013. De repente existe alguna diferencia. Saludos!

Comment: saludos hermano, gusto de leerte, vamo a solucionarlo :D *meme de squirtle* La verdad es que desconozco si sea necesario o no, el punto es que "quizás" pueda ser eso. Habrá que ver si el que redactó la pregunta logró solucionarlo :D

Comment: Ok, excelente! Gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: de nada hermano, estamos para servir, somos la hermandad de SOes y le vamos siempre con todo el power 2.0!

Answer (score 0):

No tengo Access en mi computadora para probarlo. Pero si recuerdo bien, con Access, si efectuas mas de un join, tienes que agruparlos usando paréntesis.

Algo como:

```
SELECT DISTINCT factura.n_factura, factura.data, factura.import, factura.concepte, departament.nom, programa.nom, despesa.nom, emisor.nom, destinatari.nom
FROM ((((factura
INNER JOIN departament  ON factura.departament = departament.codi)
INNER JOIN programa ON factura.programa = programa.codi)
INNER JOIN despesa ON factura.despesa = despesa.codi)
INNER JOIN emisor ON factura.emisor = emisor.codi)
INNER JOIN destinatari ON factura.destinatari = destinatari.codi;
```

También, si recuerdo bien, aunque Access acepte las paréntesis y ejecute la consulta correctamente, la próxima vez que trates de editar la consulta, puede que Access te malobre las paréntesis. Al menos, creo que eso fue mi experiencia, pero no recuerdo bien. Lo menciono para que tengas cuidado. Mi experiencia con Access siempre ha sido un tanto frustrante.

Comment: Lo probé con paréntesis y me decia que "hay un error en la sentencia" o algo así.

Comment: Si por mi fuera ya estaría solucionado con mysql y php, pero es para hacer un mini aplicativo más simple que un botijo y lo quieren en access, y Microsoft no es famoso por su buena documentación precisamente... Me tiene hartito jaja

Comment: te fijaste que hacía falta 2 paréntesis más? Uno de apertura a la izquierda de factura (línea 2) y el otro de cierre al final en lugar del punto y coma.